# Do a dry run to see if a database row is locked or not

Tags: mysql, innodb

Let's say I am trying to execute the following `UPDATE` statement in mysql (Innodb):

```
UPDATE main SET name = "Ralph" WHERE rowid=19283
```

Is there a way before doing this statement to see if there is a row/table-level lock on rowid=19283 before running this update? Or is the application strategy of dealing with deadlocks to catch the exception and then deal with them after the fact? I find that once a deadlock is reached, it's often impossible to update that row without some very loop-y logic, and so I'm seeing if the deadlock can be detected before the potential UPDATE/INSERT statement

Comment: checking up front isn't going to resolve the deadlock. So catch an exception and process it there. If you have two transactions updating the same rowid=19283, then its the application's problem to try to work out which should apply. I assume rowid is a primary/unique key. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` can show the last deadlock for debugging purposes.

Comment: @danblack thanks for that -- do you mean under the `LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK` section, or are there other section(s) too that can give info?

Comment: @danblack in theory, yes rowid is a primary key, but then it seems like this is related to a `FTS` index, which is very odd -- `RECORD LOCKS space id 326 page no 142679 n bits 320 index FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX of table` why it's raising the deadlock

Comment: need more information sorry.  Full message, queries, + `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the `main` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern is

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;  -- grab a lock on the row
... do some other processing, then eventually:
UPDATE ...   -- change the row (or maybe skip this in some cases)
COMMIT;
```

This allows multiple connections to gracefully change that row, but without stepping on each other.

No, this does not eliminate deadlocks.  It *may* turn a deadlock into a "lock wait", which is fine.

And it is not quite a "dry run".  It moves the lock from the `UPDATE` back to the `SELECT`.  If there are other things going on in this, and the competing, transaction, there could be a deadlock.

If you have 2 connections doing that transaction at "exactly" the same time, one will wait until the other finishes.  (No deadlock.)